# Date Format of full date response

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this date string:

> 2014-03-09T00:00:00+01:00

Tried to parse it to timestamp using this code:

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:response];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
NSTimeInterval timestamp = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
```

But it always returns nil in `NSLog`. What is the proper dateFormat for my date string?

I use same date format in Android app and it works but does not in Obj-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"];
```

Comment: Yes that works. I never know that Android and iOS treat date format in different ways.